# Flutter: How to launch base64 string in a external browser?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, base64, url-launcher

I'm having an image with download button in my flutter webview. On tapping download button, I'll get the base64 string of that image in the navigation delegate callback of the webview. I have to open the external browser with that base64 string.

I had used the url_launcher plugin to do that. But canLaunchUrl(url) method of that plugin return false for my base64 string. So I can't open the browser. Can anyone please tell, How to open an external browser with base64 string as url from a flutter app ?

Comment: does your base64 string have a prefix of the data type like so? `data:image/jpeg;base64,[base64String]`

Comment: @bingalooo, Yes. My base64String will start with data:image/png;base64,